# Из-за чего появляется ошибка «ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict»?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Пишу на JetpackCompose. Эта ошибка появляется и на чистом проекте, без сторонних библиотек.

Logcat:

```
W/ftworks.spammer: type=1400 audit(0.0:115667): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=17725 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c221,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.spammer
E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    Fail to get file list com.example.spammer
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```